# Have AWS Lightsail node image, need to connect to postgres hosted on AWS RDS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have a node js image that needs to connect to a postgreSQL db currently hosted on the aws rds.

The bitnami docs describe how to connect to an oracle database, here https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/nodejs/#how-to-connect-your-nodejs-application-to-an-oracle-database, but I cannot find ANY literature or anything on an analogous method to connect to a postgres db.

I assume it would be quite similar, but I'm not sure.

PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can use any PostgreSQL client available as NPM package to connect to the PostgreSQL database. For example:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg

You can find all the information of this package in its official page

https://node-postgres.com/

Run this code to start querying the PostgreSQL database

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')

// pools will use environment variables
// for connection information
const pool = new Pool()

pool.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res)
  pool.end()
})
```

You also need to specify which database to connect to:

```
PGUSER=dbuser PGHOST=database.server.com PGPASSWORD=secretpassword PGDATABASE=mydb PGPORT=3211 node script.js
```

Comment: I've installed the npm pg and trying to run psql I get ` command not found` how can I connect to the DB from ssh console of my instance?